# Not able to copy my file 1 hdd to anther

Tags: windows-7

I have 2 hard drives in my PC of 160GB and 320GB. My IS is installed on 160GB. It is working properly and another hard drive is showing in My Computer and some data is saved here, but I am not able to copy my data from 320GB drive to 160GB drive or in any removal device. Sometimes the 320GB automatically disappears from My Computer when it is running

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: What kind of hard drives do you have and how are they connected?

Answer (score 0):

First Off, Your Hard drive is most likely Failing. So you must immediately backup all the data . Since you are not able to access the Data, try running the command `chkdsk c: /f` (assuming that your drive letter is c) in cmd.

Comment: I think it's probably not C, since OP says the OS is on the other drive, not the one that's failing.

Comment: Yes c can be replaced with any drive letter.

Comment: And it wouldn't hurt running some classic checkdisk on c aswell :P

Comment: That's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your drive is failing as per Omar's suggestion, you should get another drive that is larger than the failing one (larger than 320GB + the size of the data you currently have on it) and burn a copy of [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) or similar rescue system, and use a tool like [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) to copy the failing drive to the other one. It will generate an image file that you can later mount and copy files to the remaining space on the new larger drive.